# Knapsack Dynamic Programming

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

this is a typical Knapsack problem requiring dynamic programming and there is no constraint on the supply of items. I've been working on this for my class and I tried to play around with the algorithm for hours and I'm still not getting there.

```
public static int fitBackPack(int[] W, int[] V, int T){
    int[] Opt = new int[T+1];
    Opt[0]=0;
    for (int i=1; i<=T; i++){
        int localMax=0;
        int globalMax=0;
        for (int j=0; j<W.length; j++){
            if (W[j]<=i){
                localMax = (T%W[j]<=W[j]) ?  V[j] : V[j]+Opt[T-W[j]];
                globalMax = (localMax>=globalMax) ? localMax : globalMax;
            }
        }
        Opt[i]=globalMax;
    }
    //debugging purposes
    for (int k=0; k<Opt.length; k++){
        System.out.println("Opt["+k+"] = "+Opt[k]);
    }
    return Opt[T];
}
```

This method is supposed to take a sorted array of W and V, containing the weight and the value of the item respectively, and an integer T representing the max weight. For my output, everything up until T=21 works, however, after that it just seems to be working like a greedy algorithm, which is completely not what I was hoping for. Any hints will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hints:
(x % y <= y) == true

Every now and then a truth table through your conditions with test cases will help you find these.
Better still set up some automated tests for general usage and edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

Since your algorithm is acting like a greedy one, you problem is probably on the calculation of `localMax` (since greedy algorithms look for the highest local value). By looking at your code, you seem to be getting `localMax` in the wrong way. Hint, see `Math.max()` function.

Comment: I have actually updated your code :). But I won't post it, so that you can do it on your own.